# AMD drivers for Ubuntu

Tags: amd-graphics

Recently I have bought a Ubuntu based Dell vostro 3000 laptop. It comes with core i5 processor, 8gb DDR4 ram, 1 terabyte hard disk and AMD GPU.  It has Ubuntu 16.04.3 operating system. Drivers for AMD GPU is not available and I am not able to use this GPU. How can I get drivers for my GPU?  Thanks for  any help.

Comment: Why can't you use the GPU. What is the adapter? Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|Display'` terminal command. I suspect that everything is OK with your GPU.

Comment: My pc is not starting and shutting down properly, I have to contact my seller.

Answer (score 1):

Use this command to see your kernel version:

```
uname -a
```

If your kernel version is 4.4 so you can update your kernel to 4.10 with this command:

```
sudo apt install --install-recommends linux-generic-hwe-16.04 xserver-xorg-hwe-16.04
```

this kernel support `amdgpu`.

Answer (score 1):

AMD graphics drivers not available in ubuntu 18.04 LTS(Bionic bever), But In ubuntu 18.10(Cosmic cuttlefish) have the support of AMD vega graphics drivers, [New features in 18.10](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/CosmicCuttlefish/ReleaseNotes)here the release notes, New features in 18.10 at the first line they mention that information

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem you have is the GPU-PRO driver software from AMD that is not supported bij AMD/Canonica.

read more about it here:
http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/AMDGPU-PRO-Driver-Compatibility-Advisory-with-Ubuntu-16.04.2-and-16.04.3.aspx

I't is of no use, but it will explane a lot.