# Kdenlive AMD support in Ubuntu?

Tags: amd-graphics, 18.10, amd-processor, kdenlive, amd-ryzen

I am planing on build a PC and was wondering if KDEnlive has any issues with AMD hardware? way I will be using or integrated Vega graphics or veg 56/64 or AMD Rx.

If you Have any experience with with Ryzen/KDEnlive please answer, and this is not a hardware question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AMD drivers for Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/943541/amd-drivers-for-ubuntu)

Comment: @karel it's not a duplicate because I asking about support for AMD Ryzen and compatibility with KDEnlive

Comment: I'm aware of that, but there's no way to answer your question except for you to install the app from the default Ubuntu repositories and test it on your device. Your device is compatible with the app, so you can install it and test it. If someone else installs the same app on a different device, they will get different results, so it makes more sense for you to install the app and test it yourself on your own device.

Comment: @karel I have not bought the computer and was asking if anyone had used KDEnlive with a Ryzen cpu and Vega gpu.

Comment: You should install the app and test it yourself on your own device. We're talking about editing videos here, not a calculator app.

Comment: @karel I do't have the pc yet i'm still deciding on what parts to buy. I know it works fine with Intle cpu's it's just Ryzen is cheaper and has more cores.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89082/discussion-between-karel-and-budget-tech).